# jQuery functions not affect on appeneded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQuery functions not affect on appeneded elements after ajax

I know there are two ways for thats

but evey way not the best

frist when I appened element I append jquery functions again
that mean evey append element I will appened the functions
may be that is not best

second use .live("click" instead of .on("click"

but I know .live works with old jQuery version

What is the best way to jquery functions work with elements will appended in the future

Comment: Please include the relevant code that shows your ajax and append.

Comment: *"second use .live("click" instead of .on("click" but I know .live works with old jQuery version... What is the best way to jquery functions work with elements will appended in the future"* If you look at the [`live` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/live/), it'll tell you -- use the delegating form of [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can delegate the event handling to a container to where items are appended. The full details of this technique are outlined in the jQuery documentation: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Instead of:

```js
// Attach a directly bound event handler
$( "#list a" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

you'd do

```js
// Attach a delegated event handler
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```